# textarea value = undefined on page with dynamic forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

I do not understand why I cannot access field values on forms generated dynamically via AJAX / MySQL.

The form template looks like this:

```
<form class="dishform" id='" + d.dish_id + "FF' action="#" method="post">
<fieldset>
    <label for="dish_name">Name</label>
    <textarea onblur="changedField(this);" id='" + d.dish_id + "n' name="dish_name" class="textarea-comment dish_name valid" maxlength="80">
    default text from MySQL
    </textarea>
    <label for="dish_decription">Description</label>
    <textarea onblur="changedField(this);" id='" + d.dish_id + "d' name="dish_description" class="textarea-comment dish_description valid" maxlength="240">more default text from MySQL here</textarea>
    <img src="/wp-content/uploads/menu-icons/save-dish.png" alt="Save current dish changes" class="action-menu-buttons save-curr-dish" onclick="saveDish(\'' + d.dish_id + '\')">
</fieldset>
</form>
```

The d.dish_id value is the unique table key and it looks something like "DSH0000000001".

When I hit saveDish button I call alerts to show contents of name field, and I get UNDEFINED for the value, but the right figure for defaultValue:

```
function saveDish(thisId) {

   var NameId = thisId + 'n'   <--- all ids for "name" are created as "d.dish_id + n" 

   alert("NameID= " + NameId);  <--- this shows "DSH0000000001n" so correct
   alert("DINAM= " + document.getElementById(NameId).defaultValue);   <--- this shows the defaultValue correctly to what is in the textarea from load
   alert("VAL= " + document.getElementById(NameId).Value);   <--- this one shows UNDEFINED
   alert("HARD CODED ID VAL= " + document.getElementById('DSH0000000001n').Value);   <--- this one shows UNDEFINED

};
```

Even if I hard code an ID to one of the ones I can see in inspect (that is the textarea exists with the right id), I still get UNDEFINED.

Any help is appreciated/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `saveDish`, `.Value` needs to be lowercased `.value`